# Deal with test data not having dependent variable (apply confusion matrix)

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I have these data:

training.csv:

```
A   B   D
22  1   1
32  2   1
34  3   0
44  4   1
```

testing.csv:

```
A   B
12  1
33  2
21  3
```

Note, that testing data does not include the dependent variable.

I am trying to apply different models and then use the confusion matrix.

But, because test data does not contain the dependent variable ("D"), I am receiving the message: `Error in confusionMatrix.default(X[[i]], ...) : 
  the data cannot have more levels than the reference`.

How can I overcome this situation?

If I try to create an empty column (filled with NA) to the testing data, and then apply the confusion matrix,I again receive the same error.

```
library(caret)

tr_data <- read.csv("./training.csv", header = TRUE)
t_data <- read.csv("./testing.csv", header = TRUE)

tr_data$D <- as.factor(ifelse(tr_data$D == 1, "yes", "no"))

trctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = mnLogLoss)
rpart_m <- train(D~., data = tr_data, method = "rpart", trControl = trctrl, metric = "logLoss")
rf_m <- train(D~., data = tr_data, method = "glm", trControl = trctrl, metric = "logLoss")

all_models <- list(rf = rf_m, rpart = rpart_m)
pred <- predict(all_models, newdata = t_data)

# Generate confusion matrix for each model
lapply(pred, FUN = confusionMatrix, reference = t_data$D, positive = "yes")
```

Comment: What do you expect to see? Can you please give us an example given the prediction from, let's say, the first model: `$rf: c(no, yes, no)` ?

Comment: @NatraveDrova:The numbers are random.I just want to be able to predict 1 or 0 (yes or no)

Comment: You have the predictions in the `pred` list already. Why do you need confusion matrix? I don't think there is a way to build a confusion matrix without reference data. Once you have the reference data, you can compute the matrix: `lapply(pred, FUN = confusionMatrix, reference = c("yes", "no", "no"), positive = "yes")`

Comment: As @NatraveDrova points out, the whole point of your `train` set is to build a *model*, and the whole point of your `test` set is to make predictions using the independent variable. You need to know the actual outcome (dependent variable) of your `test` set to make a confusion matrix. The confusion matrix would be on Y-axis: `predicted yes` and `predicted no` and on X-axis: `actual yes` and `actual no`.

Comment: @ChiPak:Yes.., I was wondering if there was a way to use it anyway.

Comment: As pointed by @NatraveDrove, you need actual outcome to compare against the predicted value, to build a confusion matrix. You can partition or slice the training dataset (using createDataPartition from caret package) into a training set and a validation set with data not in the training set. Build your model on the training set and use the model on the validation set to predict the outcome. You now have the predicted values and actual values with which you can build the confusion matrix.

Comment: @rajis:Ok, thanks for the suggestion.